# Task Manager thread counts and username query

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I'm new to working with powershell and I'm trying to create a script where I can check a remote machines specific process thread counts along with the username and in the output I hope I can get the highest thread user.

I'm started from this script as a reference but I can't seen to find the right commands/syntax

```
Get-Process | Select-Object Name, @{Name='ThreadCount';Expression ={$_.Threads.Count}} | Sort-Object -Property Threadcount -Descending
```

Answer (score 2):

`Get-Process` have an optional `-IncludeUserName` switch argument you can include to get the username out of the command. It will requires admin. priviledge to collect that information.

Once you have the information, you will need to group by user and then sort by the sum of threads per user to get your desired "Highest thread users".

Here is what that would look like.

```
#requires -runasadministrator
$ProcessesSummary = Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
Select-Object Name, @{Name = 'ThreadCount'; Expression = { $_.Threads.Count } },Username 

$ProcessesSummary | 
Group-Object -Property Username | 
Select Name,@{N='TotalThreads';E={($_.Group.ThreadCount |
```

Note that if you do not do anaything with `$ProcessesSummary` other than using it for the total thread per user, you can forego the first statement completely and instead just do

```
#requires -runasadministrator
Get-Process   -IncludeUserName | 
Group-Object -Property Username | 
Select Name,@{N='TotalThreads';E={($_.Group.Threads.Count | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum}} |
Sort TotalThreads -Descending | 
Where Name -NotLike 'NT*' # If you want to remove some of the system accounts from the output
```

Comment: you likely otta mention that the `-IncludeUserName` parameter  _requires_ elevated user rights. so the code needs to be "run as admin". i would likely add a `#Requires` line at the top to make that explicitly required.

Comment: Thank you!. This works perfectly!!. I used -Like to make sure I got the right output I wanted.

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey. I did mention the requirement, but I did not add the `#requires` line within the script sample itself. That's a good point though, it should definitely be there. Adding it now. Thank you for the input !

Comment: @SagePourpre - arg! i missed your `admin` info. [*blush*] you are most welcome! [*grin*]